# Different object models in same JPA persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA to work with a couple of databases with different object model in them.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="unit_1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>pu-pu-pi-du</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>my.package.items1.Class1_1</class>
    <class>my.package.items1.Class1_2</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <!-- uncomment to show sql queries in System.out -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <!-- Envers -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="unit_2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>Persistance config</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>my.package.items2.Class2_1</class>
    <class>my.package.items2.Class2_2</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <!-- uncomment to show sql queries in System.out -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

        <!-- Envers -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

When I create factory this way:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit_1", properties);
```

It works well, but updates the databast of unit_1 with all of the classes from unit_2. factory.metamodel.entities will contain all 4 classes:

- my.package.items1.Class1_1
- my.package.items1.Class1_2
- my.package.items2.Class2_1
- my.package.items2.Class2_2

And two more tables from model are added to database from unit_1.

How to explain JPA, that database of unit_1 has nothing common with unit_2 and I don't need its mappings?

Comment: Tried "exclude-unlisted-classes" ?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400482/jpa-hibernate-schema-generation-with-multiple-persistence-units . I'm hesitant to mark as a true duplicate as the linked question/answer only partly overlaps.

Comment: @Neil Stockton thank you, I didn't know about this param

Comment: @Gimby yes, you're right. Our questions are different, overlapping and are solved by same fix

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following param after ''class'' tags in both of ''persistence-unit''

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```